# Can we use mutex in device drivers, etc. during startup?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mutex, startup

I wonder that at start up time, the kernel need to load device driver for initializing e.g. cpu clock. But at this time, the kernel has not initialized completely yet. So that we can use the mutex at this time (because device object use mutex as protect mechanism)? When will mutex be available to use?

Comment: After the scheduler is ready, mutexes are usable. So, normally, you may use mutexes anywhere. But needing to use mutex during device's initialization stage looks **suspicious**: there is no concurrency during that stage.

Comment: I mean before scheduler starting, kernel needs to init some peripheral like system timer, cpu clock... so it will call init methods from driver objects. But the driver object are usally protected by mutex. So how kernel deals with this?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need a small glance into the Linux kernel initialisation process.

The kernel is kicked off by a single process, running on a single core.

It detects the number of CPUs available and some other stuff, and configures the scheduler. It then triggers the scheduler.

Any driver loading or so will only happen after this point.

In fact, drivers are loaded way after the scheduler has been started up.

Some great insights into the topic of Linux initialisation:
[Linux inside.](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/)